# Deleting vector lines beyond image extents using QGIS?

Tags: raster, vector, qgis-2, clip, extents

I am using QGIS 2.2

I have one vector line layer (roads) that stretches beyond my base image (see below).

[image]

I wish to have the roads "clipped/trimmed or deleted" right at the edge of the image's extent (see below):

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you edit the question to indicate what software you're working in?

Comment: Search for your software product and clip, eg [ArcMap clip](https://www.google.com.au/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=arcmap+clip&safe=off) or [QGIS clip](https://www.google.com.au/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=qgis%20clip&safe=off) - chances are you'll find step-by-step instructions

Comment: A picture would be nice too. Are you hoping to limit your vector to the extent (Xmin,Ymin - Xmax,Ymax) or active area (without NoData cells)? This makes a big difference in how difficult it's likely to be, but we do need to know what software you are using to be able to help at all.

Answer (score 1):

QGIS does not appear to have direct functionality to clip a vector layer by the extent of a raster layer. You can only clip by another vector layer.  However, you can use the plug-in Image Boundary to create a polygon that matches the boundary of the raster layer. With that in hand, you can use Vector->GeoProcessing Tools->Clip to clip the vector you're trying to limit.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a long time since this was asked, but for posterity:

In QGIS 2.18, you can clip a vector to the extent of a raster using the OGR "Clip vectors by extent" tool, accessible through the Processing Toolbox.

First, load your vector layer and raster layer into QGIS.

Set your input layer to the vector layer you want to clip.

For Clip Extent, choose the box on the right-hand side of the textbox, and choose 'Use layer/canvas extent', and choose the layer that represents your raster.

The only major caveat is that the CRS of the vector file has to match the CRS of the raster file. The extents of a layer are defined by the layer's CRS, not the CRS of the project. The CRS of the vector and raster layer can be different than the CRS of your project, they just have to match.