# How to crop a vector shapefile according to raster?

Tags: qgis, raster, vector, polygonize

I am trying to clip a vector shapefile- points according to a DEM in QGIS. I used GDAL function and polygonized the DEM. Then I ran the Vector-Geoprocessing tools-clip in order to crop the vector data points. The whole QGIS crashed couple of times while doing this and I have never achieved any results. Could you please suggest any alternative steps for me? Many thanks!

Comment: are you asking the same question as [this](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/110073/deleting-vector-lines-beyond-image-extents-using-qgis)?

Answer (score 0):

Instead polygonized the DEM you can build a shapefile as a raster tile index (inside the same menu or gdaltindex) then you can crop the vector.

input directory: link to the DEM´s folder
output shapefile: tile idex